# Argumento tiene longitud 0 en loop while

Tags: r, lista, bucles, while

Estoy programando un 3 en raya en una matriz de 10x10.

Aquí, estamos en la función que se encarga de comprobar si las fichas son consecutivas, para declarar ganador o pasar al siguiente turno.

Por lo tanto hemos puesto una condición para evitar que se salga de los límites de la matriz (`m`), ya que al estar checkeando la vertical hacia abajo, pues que sea menor o igual que la fila `10` que es la última y nos da error de que la longitud del argumento es cero.

`nbsymbols` es el número de fichas consecutivas necesarias para hacer partida, `insert_row` es el número de fila que inserta el usuario y `insert_col` la columna.

Les adjunto el código a ver si me pueden resolver algo:

```
checkconsecutive<-function(m, insert_row, insert_col, turn, V)
{
  fichas=1
  consecutive=TRUE
  repeat
  {
    i=1
    while((fichas<=V[[nbsymbols]])&(consecutive=TRUE)&(m[insert_row+i, insert_col]<=m[10, ])) #check vertical abajo
    {
      if(m[insert_row+i, insert_col]==m[insert_row, insert_col])
      {
        fichas=fichas+1
        consecutive=TRUE
        i=i+1
      } else
      {
        consecutive=FALSE
```

Y el error:

> Error in while ((fichas <= V[[nbsymbols]]) & (consecutive = TRUE) & (m[insert_row +  : 
>     argumento tiene longitud cero

Comment: Bienvenida Claudia a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Es muy importante que veas [mcve] ya que tu código está incompleto e imposible de hacer un debug o entender dónde está el problema. Trata de subirlo completo y explicar que valores puede recibir cada parámetro. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Parece que el código está incompleto, pero a simple vista en la condición 
 
`... & (consecutive = TRUE) & ...`
 tiene un solo signo = , la condición debería ser `consecutive == TRUE`, o simplemente `... & consecutive & ...` , dado que es un booleano.

Comment: Sí, me di cuenta de que había puesto un solo = en vez de dos nada más subir la pregunta, pero ese no es problema, ya que me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Sería bueno que vuelvas a subir el código, porque está incompleto. En el while hay un parámetro indexado `V[[nbsymbols]]`. V ¿es una lista? el índice nbsymbols de donde sale? No se lo ve inicializado ni tampoco es un parámetro de la función. S